# UISwitch to edit value of another loaded view

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a Tab Bar Controller with 2 items.  One has a switch that edits a setting for the other View, that will already be loaded.  How can I reload the view to accommodate for any possible modifications of the switch?  I've tried using `ViewWillAppear`, but didn't work for what I need to do.  What other ways are there of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider `NotificationCenter`.

Comment: How would I do that?